# View ubuntu server in desktop version

Tags: 14.04, server, ubuntu-gnome, .desktop, gnome-classic

I'm new to Ubuntu server.I have `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-88-generic x86_64)` installed. I've also installed `ubuntu-desktop` & `gnome`.

When I `ssh root@my-ip-address` and do a `cd /usr/share/xsessions/` and `ls`, I can see I have all these `gnome-classic.desktop  gnome.desktop  ubuntu.desktop`.

I'm on a Mac and running all these commands from my terminal *(I don't have Virtual box installed)*.

The reason I installed `ubuntu-desktop` & `gnom` was to be able to see a graphic-version of the server/system.

*I installed them by doing `sudo tasksel`.*

What do I need to do & how can I get the system up and see my server as a normal ubuntu desktop.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you restart the system?

Comment: Related: [How to set up a headless server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6/how-to-set-up-a-headless-server/943059#943059)

Comment: "The reason I installed ubuntu-desktop & gnom was to be able to see a graphic-version of the server/system" You do not have a server. You created a desktop system. And I really advice to NOT do it like this. Learn command line and use tools from your Mac to connect to the server (workbench, or phpmyadmin to access mysql for instance, webmin etc).

Comment: Probably you have to run `startx`. Did you try that? And gnome is quite "heavy" for a server .. better use a lighter GUI like xfce4 e.g. this is installed by just using `sudo apt install xfce4`

Comment: @George Yes I did with `reboot now` and it said shutting down and I did SSH in once again but nothing happened.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for the advice. Reason I installed it was because I'm building an application which I need to have firefox and chrome installed to my server. The reason I want to see the desktop is to start up Firefox and some other programs. How can I do that from my terminal?

Comment: @derHugo Thanks. I ran `sudo apt install xfce4`. How can I start it now? I ran `startx` and it did some lines and stopped and now just waiting

Comment: You are using the wrong tool: a server is not for that kind of coding. If you want to keep going this way: install remote desktop software on your mac and connect with that to your other desktop. But you really should use a VM for this kind of thing.

Comment: You start it by `startx` as mentioned. BUT: the question Rinzwind wants to have cleared first: Are you on the terminal of your server or are you connected remotely to the server?

Comment: Ok in your comment below I saw that you connected remotely. This doesn't work like that because the xServer rendering your GUI can not be forwarded just like that through the SSh connection!! Have a search in the Net for "ubuntu forward xserver"

Comment: If you need a graphic interface for your server use a web based solution such as webmin.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you did not install any display managers, try

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

and try again.

Comment: I ran your giving command I got this: **lightdm is already the newest version**. What do I need to do now?

Comment: How are you trying to access the GUI? From a monitor attached to the server or remotely?

Comment: I'm trying to access GUI remotely from my own Mac

Comment: What program? VNC?

Comment: No program, from my terminal.

Comment: You can't access the GUI from a terminal

Comment: What do I need to have or installed in order to get access to GUI?

Comment: A program such as VNC will work fine. Just google a guide and install a VNC client on your mac.

Comment: You need to look at X forwarding - https://www.hoffman2.idre.ucla.edu/access/x11_forwarding/

Comment: I don't believe that X11 forwarding will work on Mac OS X though

Comment: Thanks @NerdOfLinux I installed XQuartz and did `cd /etc/ssh` and `sudo vim ssh_config` and changed `ForwardAgent` & `ForwardX11` to **YES**. Logged out with XQuartz terminal and did `ssh -X root@IP` but nothing happens, I also did `ssh -Y root@IP`. When I run `starx`, I says `Build Operating System` and bunch of other lines and then it says **qxl_kms_surface_create: Bad bpp: 1 (1)** and it just like it takes a break and nothing happens. Appreciate your help